# Parameter missing when checked with keys() function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, jupyter-notebook, parameters

This is done in jupyter notebook. peak_posn and nu_e are both arrays, while nu_e, B_e and alpha_e are variables

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model

def function(nu_e, B_e, alpha_e, n):
    wavenumber = nu_e + 2*n*(B_e*alpha_e) - alpha_e*(n**2)
    return wavenumber

model = Model(function)

# make a best fit of our data
fit_results = []
for i in range(len(n_vals)):
    results = model.fit(peak_posn, nu_e=2500, B_e=100, alpha_e=0.5, n=n_vals[i])
    fit_results.append(results)
    parameters = results.params
    
    # Check the keys present in the parameters dictionary
    print(parameters.keys())
```

However, when I print this out, the parameters I get are just B_e, alpha_e and n, what am I doing wrong with this?

I have tried

```
params = model.make_params(nu_e=50, B_e=10, alpha_e=0.1, n=n_vals[i])
results = model.fit(peak_posn, params)
```

and

```
params = Parameters()
params.add('nu_e', value=2500)
params.add('B_e', value=5)
params.add('alpha_e', value=0.5)
params.add('n', value=n_vals[i])
```

but the results I get when I try calling for the `nu_e` parameter are

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 42
     40 alpha = results.params['alpha_e'].value
     41 alpha_err = results.params['alpha_e'].stderr
---> 42 nu = results.params['nu_e'].value
     43 nu_err = results.params['nu_e'].stderr
     44 # print them

KeyError: 'nu_e'
```